# Flutter: overriding text style for dropdown menu items cancels auto-display of disabled state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `PopupMenuButton` with nested `PopupMenuItem`s, each of them in turn have a nested `Text`. One of `PopupMenuItem`s can be `enabled`/disabled which is controlled by the corresponding property and is displayed accordingly (with bright/pale color).

```
Widget popupMenu(SharedPreferences prefs) {
final themeManager = Provider.of<ThemeManager>(context);
return PopupMenuButton(
  onSelected: (selected) {
    switch (selected) {
      case MenuItems.switchTheme:
        themeManager.switchTheme();
        prefs.setBool(
            describeEnum(Prefs.manuallySetDark),
            themeManager.isThemeDark()
        );
        break;
      case MenuItems.autoSwitchTheme:
        prefs.setBool(
            describeEnum(Prefs.manuallySetDark),
            null
        );
        themeManager.updateTheme(null, _model.isDarkTimeOfDay);
        break;
    }
  },
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
  [
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: MenuItems.switchTheme,
      child: Text('Switch color scheme'),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: MenuItems.autoSwitchTheme,
      child: Text('Auto-switch color scheme'),
      enabled: prefs.getBool(describeEnum(Prefs.manuallySetDark)) != null,
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

So far so good. But with the following theme, `subtitle1` style is applied to the `Text` in `PopupMenuItem`s which is not what I'd like to see there.

```
final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.grey[800]),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[800], fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo, fontSize: 16),
    caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo, fontSize: 16),
    button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
  ),
```

If I override the style for the `Text` it is displayed with the correct style but it no longer respects the `enabled` property.

```
PopupMenuItem(
  value: MenuItems.switchTheme,
  child: Text('Auto-switch color scheme', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button),
  enabled: prefs.getBool(describeEnum(Prefs.manuallySetDark)) != null,
),
```

Isn't it something expected? Is it worth an issue on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `PopupMenuItem` has a `textStyle` property saying:

> The text style of the popup menu item.
> If this property is null, then PopupMenuThemeData.textStyle is used. If PopupMenuThemeData.textStyle is also null, then ThemeData.textTheme.subtitle1 is used.

So the following theme works as expected without modifying the code which builds the `PopupMenuItem`s:

```
final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.grey[800]),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[800], fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo, fontSize: 16),
    caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo, fontSize: 16),
    button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
  ),
  // addition:
  popupMenuTheme: PopupMenuThemeData(
    color: Colors.grey[800],
    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
  ),
);
```